# How do you make a shape move along a Bezier Curve SFML?

Tags: c++, game-physics, sfml

I'm making this game wherein the object should move along a Bezier Curve, I've already computed and successfully drawn the tangent and normal line, but I can't seem to make the Box move along the direction of the tangent. I'm really new in SFML, hope someone could give an advice and direction.

Edited: Like for example, I want to move the object from (0,0) coordinate to (3, 7) when I press only the right arrow key. I know that I should use the concept of vector and normalization but I don't understand the tutorial videos that I watched about it.

Comment: what did you try and how does it fail? You cannot except an answer to give a full tutorial on how to move an object in SFML (and asking for existing tutorials is offtopic either). Here is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720118/make-object-move-smoothly-in-c-sfml

Comment: what exactly dont you understand? I dont know SFML, but if you want to move from 0,0 to 3,7 then you probably have to calculate intermediate points (you say you have the splines already, so this should be doable) and then move the object along those points

Comment: First of all, think about of what you consider to be your speed. If the point in time is okay to correspond to the bezier curve parameter, well, you are essentially done, aren't you? Center is the point on the bezier curve and direction is the tangent direction.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this problem, detecting input and then actually moving your object. Presuming you've got the input covered (please say if not) then I'll focus on moving the object:

If an object inherits from `sf::Transformable`, you will be able to use many transform functions such as `setPosition(x,y)` and `move(x,y)` (they do different things!)

A basic example based on yours, using `sf::RectangleShape` which inherits from `sf::Transformable`:

```
sf::RectangleShape shape({5.f,5.f}); // A square, 5 pixels wide

sf::Vector2f movementThisFrame(3.f,7.f); //this would be the value from your curve

if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
    shape.move(movementThisFrame);
```

A few things to mention:

- You may find using events for input works better, especially if you only want one action per press (isKeyPressed directly queries the key's state, whereas events send you pressed/released events once
- `move()` is relative to the current position, whereas `setPosition()` is absolute, don't forget that!